# tutum stackfile with relative volume path

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I want to convert my docker-compose.yml to a [tutum stackfile](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000583471).
In the docker-compose.yml I'm using a relative path for the volume:

`web
  volumes:
    - './web:/web'`

Which accomplishes, that the local folder ./web, where the docker-compose.yml  resides, is added as a volume to the web docker service.

stackfiles from tutum on the other hand only allow absolute paths.
Changing it to

`web
  volumes:
    - '/web:/web'`

has the result, that my Dockerfile can't find the folder /web anymore.
How to accomplish this with a stackfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use volumes anymore because the host running the container isn't going to have access to your source code.  You need to build the image with the source code inside it using `COPY` or `ADD` in the Dockerfile.